# Remove one directory from full directory path

Tags: c#

I have a directory path of `C:\Subdir1\Subdir2\Subdir3\filename.xml`.

I need to first check if the file, `filename.xml` exists in the root of `"Subdir2"` (one level back) before looking in `"Subdir3"`.  How can I easly parse this with `Path.GetPathRoot(filename)`?

I.E.

First see if this is true:

> C:\Subdir1\Subdir2\filename.xml

If not true, then default to `C:\Subdir1\SubDir2\Subdir3\filename.xml` for the file.

Comment: Hi all, this is the code I ended up using:

if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(filename).Parent.FullName,Path.GetFileName(filename))))            {
   filename = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(filename).Parent.FullName,Path.GetFileName(filename));
}

Answer (score 18):

```
Directory.GetParent(dir).FullName
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this one    `Directory.GetParent`
and `System.IO.File.Exists`