# C#: Need to remove last folder from file name path

Tags: c#

I'm pulling a file path from a database to use as a file source.
I need to remove the last folder from the source path, so I can then create new folders to use as the destination path.

Example source file path:
`\\\\ServerName\\Documents\\MasterDocumentFolder\\`

I need to remove the last folder from that string and get this:
`\\\\ServerName\\Documents\\`

So I can create a folder like this:
`\\\\ServerName\\Documents\\NewDocumentFolder1\\`

Edit: I have updated my example paths to show why the Path.GetDirectoryName() won't work in this case.

Comment: Do your strings come back from the database with all the slashes doubled? Or is that just what you are observing in the debugger (which is normal)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove one directory from full directory path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098209/remove-one-directory-from-full-directory-path)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

What you are looking for is the GetParent() method in the Directory class

```
string path = @"C:\Documents\MasterDocumentFolder\";
DirectoryInfo parentDir = Directory.GetParent(path);
// or possibly
DirectoryInfo parentDir = Directory.GetParent(path.EndsWith("\\") ? path : string.Concat(path, "\\"));

// The result is available here
var myParentDir = parentDir.Parent.FullName
```

Comment: That results in `C:\Documents\MasterDocumentFolder`

Comment: No, it results in an object that you can render to what you stated, but it also contain the Parent property.

Comment: `GetParent()` retrieves the parent directory. Only with the trailing \ it doesn't quite work as expected. So you either drop the trailing \ or use the `Parent` to go up one more. In either case, your answer doesn't yield the correct result.

Comment: Added an usage example for DirectoryInfo.Parent and it is the correct way of solving this issue in .net

Comment: Not really correct.  If the path contains a trailing '\', then the example (incl the use of Parent) works correctly.  If not, then the preceeding folder is stripped when using Parent, leading, essentially,  to two folders being dropped. If this is based on processing a user-input path, you cannot rely on this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jon The only way to correctly describe a folder in c# is by having a \ in the end of it, paths not ending with a backslash indicates that it is a file. Did however update the solution with an alternative

Comment: Related discussion: [Bug in Directory.GetParent ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3964037/11683) (which in fact [caused](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/614862/inconsistent-behavior-for-directory-getparent) this behaviour to be properly documented)

Answer (score 12):

Thats ugly, but works

```
string path = @"C:\Documents\MasterDocumentFolder\file.any";
var lastFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
var pathWithoutLastFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(lastFolder);
```

But if you have less than one level of directories (drive root), then `pathWithoutLastFolder` will be `null`, so you have to deal with it.

Comment: Unless he has a Full Path (including filename) then only a single `Path.GetDirecotyrName()` would be required.

Comment: I have updated my example paths to show why that method isn't working for me. Is there an extra step to convert \\ to \ ?

Comment: @Trikks take a look on `DirectoryInfo.Parent` with Reflector. You will be surprised - it uses `string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);`

Comment: That sais that someone already wrote that code for us then doesn't it? :)

Comment: @Trikks well, agree `Directory.GetParent(path).Parent.FullName;` looks better, +1 for your solution

Comment: If the path ends in a backslash then `Path.GetDirectoryName(path)` just strips the backslash and doesn't remove the leaf-level directory.  I've got around this using `Path.GetDirectoryName(path.Trim().TrimEnd('\\'))`.  The first `Trim` is to ensure the `TrimEnd` will still strip a trailing backslash even if it's followed by a space.

Answer (score 7):

[System.IO.DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is probably the cleanest way to accomplish what you're asking for.

```
var path = "\\\\ServerName\\Documents\\MasterDocumentFolder\\";
string newPath = new DirectoryInfo(path).Parent.CreateSubdirectory("NewDocumentFolder1").FullName;
Console.WriteLine(newPath.FullName);
//> "\\ServerName\Documents\NewDocumentFolder1\"
```

Note that DirectoryInfo does NOT require an existing or accessible directory:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Asdf\Qwer\Zxcv\Poiu\Lkj\Mn");
Console.WriteLine( dir.Exists );
//> False
```

But making sure it exists is a snap

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Asdf\Qwer\Zxcv\Poiu\Lkj\Mn");
dir.Create();
Console.WriteLine( dir.Exists );
//> True
```

It will also do nifty things like resolve relative paths:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Asdf\Qwer\Zxcv\Poiu\Lkj\..\..\..\Mn");
Console.WriteLine( dir.FullName );
//> C:\Asdf\Qwer\Mn
```

Regarding other answers trimming and appending slashes, note the difference in behavior between Directory.GetParent("...\") and DirectoryInfo("...\").Parent when dealing with trailing \'s - DirectoryInfo is more consistent:

```
Console.WriteLine( Directory.GetParent( @"C:\Temp\Test" ).FullName );
//> C:\Temp
Console.WriteLine( Directory.GetParent( @"C:\Temp\Test\" ).FullName );
//> C:\Temp\Test
Console.WriteLine( new DirectoryInfo( @"C:\Temp\Test" ).Parent.FullName );
//> C:\Temp
Console.WriteLine( new DirectoryInfo( @"C:\Temp\Test\" ).Parent.FullName );
//> C:\Temp
```

Again, to avoid dealing with trailing slashes, always use Path.Combine() to concatenate paths and file names. It will handle paths correctly whether they contain a trailing \ or not:

```
Console.WriteLine( Path.Combine( @"C:\Temp\Test\", "Test.txt" ) );
//> C:\Temp\Test\Test.txt
Console.WriteLine( Path.Combine( @"C:\Temp\Test", "Test.txt" ) );
//> C:\Temp\Test\Test.txt
Console.WriteLine( Path.Combine( @"C:\", "Temp", "Test", "Test.txt" ) );
//> C:\Temp\Test\Test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This should account for the path being either a file or directory

```
DirectoryInfo parent = null;
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    parent = new FileInfo(path).Directory.Directory
}
if(Directory.Exists(path))
{
    parent = new DirectoryInfo(path).Directory;
}
```

Comment: Your expression should perhaps include DirectoryInfo.Exists?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried splitting the string per "\", and then reconstructing a new path by joining every element but the last one?

You would also need to consider the case where the original path is at the root, and when it ends in a backslash or not.

Comment: .net includes the System.IO namespace and Path object for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

With this method you can create dir by dirPath (if dir is not exist) and to create directory from the filePath if needed

```
private void CreateDirIfNotExist(string dirPath, bool removeFilename = false)
{
    if (removeFilename)
        dirPath = Directory.GetParent(dirPath).FullName;

    if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In VB:

```
Dim MyNewPath As String = StrReverse(Strings.Split(StrReverse(MyPath), "\", 2)(1))
```

This works down to the root, eg `C:\MyPath` but fails (without validation) for a bare folder.

Obviously, you need to handle differently if there is a file appended.