# Removing last string after \

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove last string after \ using lastindexof but I can't figure how to do this.

This is the example of the string I want to parse:

```
string path = "C:\Program Files\Google\";
string path2 = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\";
```

I want to remove the Google or Chrome in the path, but if I use the lastindexof '\' it will not work. So what is the fastest or standard way to do this in c#.

EDIT: This is just an example and I'm not working for path.

Comment: If you are processing file paths use the `Path` class in the `System.IO` namespace. For example the [GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove one directory from full directory path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098209/remove-one-directory-from-full-directory-path)

Comment: I'm not working for path/directory I just need to remove the last string. So I can apply it to other things.

Comment: There must be a dozen questions on SO discussing LastIndexOf... This one should be closed.

Comment: What if it is `C:\ ` or `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LastIndexOf() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596916/lastindexof-method)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you don't do it this way at all - use [`Directory.GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the parent directory:

```
string path2 = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\";
var parentFolder = Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(path2)).FullName;
```

Comment: That will give you `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome` (at least it is for me)...

Comment: Ah true - odd behavior - fixed by extracting the directory name first

Comment: The OP specifically said he does not work with paths. While the information is correct, it doesn't answer his question.

Comment: That part was edited in after I had written my answer

Comment: @BrokenGlass - so modify your answer or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

One standard way is to use `System.IO.Directory.GetParent`. Note, however, that if the path has a trailing separator, you need to apply `GetParent` twice. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using System.IO;

if (path.EndsWith("\\"))
{
    path = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(path).FullName).FullName;
}
else
{
    path = Directory.GetParent(path).FullName;
}
```

**UPDATE:** For a more general string-based approach:

```
var a = @"a\b\c\";
var b = a.LastIndexOf("\\", a.Length-2);
var c = a.Substring(0, b);
```

`LastIndexOf` allows the use of a starting index from which to look backward. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The OP specifically said he does not work with paths. While the information is correct, it doesn't answer his question.

Comment: The question was altered after my answer was given.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is your answer.

```
string path2 = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\";
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
for (i = path2.Length; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (path2[i-1] == '\\')
    {
        count++;
        if(count == 2) //Change the condition according to your requirement.
            break;     //For example if you want upto last third "\" then put 3 in the condition
    }
}
path2 = path2.Substring(0, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

`TrimEnd('\\')` your string and then use last index.